# Structuring  a website in Liferay Portal?

Tags: web, structure, liferay

I am working on a project involving Liferay Portal and am hoping to get some input on how to properly utilize 'community' and 'organizations' in the site structure. I have thus far been frustrated with the lack of documentation on this subject, and Liferay's internal forum seems to be all but dead. Can the community assist me or point me in the right direction for my needs?

Comment: To give hints on how to "properly utilize community and organizations" it would help to know what you actually intend to do. Especially for that "properly" part of your question. Information about what the difference between communities and organizations is has been given below. Please refine your question in order to get a useful answer for your situation.

Answer (score 1):

The main difference between Communities and Organizations in Liferay is that the organizations can be organized into a hierarchy. In all other aspects they are almost identical.
Have a look at the chapter "Portal Architecture" in the [Liferay Administration guide](http://docs.liferay.com/portal/5.2/official/liferay-administration-guide.pdf).

Liferay does lack documentation. So, usually your best guide in Liferay is your experience ;-). Or experience of the experienced Liferay developers.

I think you already visited forums, wiki and blogs at the Liferay web-site. Additionally, you can have a look at the site of the Liferay platinum partner - Cignex. They published 2 rather useful books on Liferay and they also have a blog with some useful tips.

Answer (score 1):

Main differences between Communities & Organizations:

- Hierarchy
- User self-subscription (e.g. users can be allowed to browser & join communities)

Behind the scenes, they're both "groups" and eventually, the distinction may be eliminated.

Answer (score 0):

community and organizations in code level are both group

Answer (score 0):

I can give you example of Org. If one person (XYZ), is employed by ABC as a Team Lead and working in Pune. So he is a member of ABC corp. Second he is a member of Team Lead Org, and he is member of Pune part. So we need to create parent org named ABC under that we need to create child org named team lead and work location etc. and Comm is like different aspect of our organisation.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to point out a blog post by Jorge Ferrer on Organizations or Communities which you can find here: http://www.liferay.com/web/jorge.ferrer/blog/-/blogs/7858337

He explains the purpose of creating Communities and Organizations from Liferay Portal's perspective. Its a good way to understand the purpose of Comms and orgs and when and where to use them.

Here is an excerpt:

> - **Communities:** they were created as a way to have groups of pages that    could display content and applications. The reason why they
>     were    called communities is because the goal of all the initial
>     implementations was to build online communities, but since then
>     people have really been using communities for things for which the
>     term may not apply so well such as corporate sites, product sites,
>     event sites, etc. That's perfectly fine.
> - **Organizations:** they were created as a way to organize users in a    hierarchy. The great thing of this hierarchy is that it allows
>     delegation of user administration, which is a key feature needed by
>     some of the largest installations of Liferay where there are hundreds 
>     of thousands or even millions of users. Later, we realized that many
>     people were creating a community associated to each (or several) of
>     their organizations. But keeping this association manually was a bit
>     of a pain, so we improved organizations so that they could have their 
>     own site. (For the curious, we did it by creating a community
>     underneath but  hiding that fact from the end user).

Answer (score 0):

I really disagree with comments provided up, specifying that Liferay documentation is not proper.

Whether its liferay or any other open source technology you can't get all answers in documentation or help. Take a e.g of spring/java/fuse/camel/struts/hibernate etc.

Anyhow to answer to exact question asked. Please refer the below link and in case of further queries, please revert back.

https://www.liferay.com/web/jorge.ferrer/blog/-/blogs/organizations-or-communities-which-one-should-i-use-the-final-answer